# Computationally complex irrational numbers

Tags: computational-complexity, irrational-numbers

Are there irrational numbers for which we know that computing its nth digit would take (at least) linear/polynomial/exponential/superexponential time (wrt to length of n and with "big enough" n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is. Just define an irrational number $x=0.r_1r_2r_3\ldots$ where $r_i$ is an integer computed in linear/polynomial/exponential/superexponential time (i.e. asymptotic to $O(i),O(i^n) $ etc).

For example, you can set $r_i$ is the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,i\}$ whose members sum to a prime number. (I have no idea what the time complexity of this is but I guess with a naive algorithm it would be $O(2^i)$). Then computing $n$ digits of $x$ is done in exponential time. Note that even if $r_i>9$ then just stick $r_i$ onto the end of the decimal expansion of $x$.

In order to make computing $n$ digits of $x$ exactly exponential time, you can change the previous definition to $r_i$ is the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,i\}$ whose members sum to a prime number, mod $10$. Then I'm pretty sure that as long as you're using the naive algorithm, the calculation is in exponential time.

Similar methods can be used to find irrational numbers that are calculated in any other time complexity.

Comment: Even before you get to that, you don't know that computation of $r_i$ is intractable, but you could probably work around that by choosing a known-intractable problem.  But to show irrationality requires only showing that $r_i$ is non-periodic, which might not be hard at all.

Comment: This is non-rigorous, but it would have to be a HUGE coincidence for my choice of $r_i$ to turn out to create a rational $x$. In any case, without a closed form solution for $r_i$ (I don't know if it is possible or not), one can never know if $x$ is rational or not. But looking at it, there seems to be nothing there that would cause periodicity.

Comment: I have no idea and in this particular case I'm pretty sure it won't be elementary. It may be more fruitful to find a better definition of $r_i$, which is clearly irrational and exponentially complex. I'm sure it won't be too hard. This example served more as an intuitive and off-the-top-of-my-head example.

Comment: @rank I don't quite understand what you mean. You are assuming that we may know that $\{r_i\}$ is periodic? Clearly, if we know that then $x$ is rational, but how can we tell for a sequence of exponential complexity whether or not it is periodic?

Comment: @rank Now I see what you mean. If we know that a problem is periodic, it is guaranteed to be computable in constant time (maybe a little worse if you need modulo). I guess what I meant is that in the answer that I gave, on would have to make sure that it is in fact non-periodic, both in order for $x$ to be irrational and for its decimal expansion to actually be complex enough.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a complete answer. But we should note first that there are irrational numbers for which computing the $n$th digit is impossible! See Wikipedia's [Computable Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) page.
We can prove this simply by counting. There are only a countable number of Turing Machines, thus a countable number of algorithms for computing irrational numbers. But there are an uncountable number of irrational numbers. So we cannot compute them all.

An example of an uncomputable number is [Chaitin's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant).

But I don't have many good examples of irrational numbers along with time to compute them. There is a [formula for the $n$th digit of pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_.CF.80) but I'm not sure of the exact running time (edit: see Micah's comment below)~. That page also has similar formulae for e.g. $\ln(2)$.

Comment: The [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of $\pi$ is bounded above by $8$, meaning that -- in the very worst possible case -- you only need to compute $8$ times as many digits as you already have to know what to do about rounding.