Irrational numbers as "periods" in discrete sequences based on complex exponentials
Main string description
To keep the core of the question short, I leave the context introduction at the end of this text. Here I describe a construction that is related to that introduction, but to answer the question you could just start reading from here.
Given N colored dots describing  a curve in space $\vec{\mathbf{X_n}}$ , created by a single array of complex numbers $Z_n$ created recursively.
$$\vec{\mathbf{X_n}}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
Considering:
$$n  \in \space \mathbb{N}_0$$
$$T_o  \in \space \mathbb{Q}$$
We have
$$
r_k=
\begin{cases}
0 &  k  < 0 \\
r_{k-1}+\Delta r_o & \space k \geq 0 \text{ and } k \equiv 0 \pmod{M} \\
r_{k-1} & \space   k > 0 \text{ and } k \not\equiv 0 \pmod{M}
\end{cases}
$$
$$k  \in \space \mathbb{Z}$$
So :
$$\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T_o}}$$
$$Z_n=r_n\omega^n$$
Coloring
The color $C_n$ in these examples is based on  "hsv" or "coolwarm" colormaps with $M_c$ colors:
$$C_n \equiv n \pmod{M_{c}}$$
Coordinates
And cartesian coordinates for the sequences describing a curve in space:
$$\vec{\mathbf{X_n}}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
$$\Omega_o=\frac{2\pi }{T_o}$$
And the spatial coordinates arrays for index $n$
$$u_n=\frac{1}{2}(Z_n+\overline{Z_n})=r_n cos[\Omega_o n]$$
$$v_n=\frac{1}{2i}(Z_n-\overline{Z_n})=r_n sin[\Omega_o n]$$
$$w_n=log_{2}(|Z_n|)$$
Examples with just one curve in space where periodicity is shown by the color of the scatter plot
The gray colored lines are the line between two consecutive dots.
$M=13$ $M_c=13$ $T_o=13$
Because of the properties of the roots of unity, for rational $T_o$ we will always have periodicity in $\omega^n$

$M=1$ $M_c=13$ $T_o=13$

$M=1$ $T_o=M_c=3$

$M=1$ with big $T_o=M_c=10^5$

Evolves to:

Question: What about irrational $T_o=\varphi$ corresponding to an integer $M_c$ providing some sense of "irrational-periodicity"
$$\varphi=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$$
It is well known that, When dealing with "discrete-time" sequences, if $T_o$ is  an irrational number,  the traditional sense of periodicity fails, so  $f[n+P] \neq f[n]$
$$\omega^{n}\omega^{P}\neq\omega^{n}$$
$$\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T_o}}$$
$$P \in \mathbb{N}$$
But clearly there is some periodicity in an extended sense, that can be seen in this graphs. I'd like to know how is this kind of periodicity  properly described in math.
In this plots we use a rational approximations of an irrational number, what delivers a drifting effect that is very convenient to describe a predictable pattern that is not periodic in the traditional sense, and that appears to use the space more efficiently.
$M_c=M=13$ $T_o=\varphi$

Evolves to:



Other irrational example $T_o=\sqrt{2}$ and $M_c=16$

Introduction at the end, The order matters : Math, Rhythm, Counting, Monads, Particles, Universe
Disclaimer: This is  a recreational math question from a math hobbyist  looking for guidance
This is TLDR introduction for the question, but the reason is to give context of why I'm looking for guidance and good reads on how to describe some mathematical definitions as periodicity in an extended sense.
I left this at the end so the important part of the question is at the top.
I saw a post in X  that said:
"Numbers are particles"
I immediately thought I agree, without even  understanding clearly the meaning  in the real world of such a statement. just thought in my infinite ignorance, I agree. That sounds nice.
That's what I've been thinking  about monads, trying to understand how just the process of evolving-time could be enough to create geometry and this way creating everything that is observable, expanding from an initial spatial and temporal coordinate and evolving according to  a simple set of initial rules.
Math is the best infinite game available for  humans (not only mathematicians), and I had the "irrational" impulse of start working on a model of a toy-universe where  math is creating everything using the energy and information associated to the beat of a "drum" or the tick of a "clock" at the center of coordinates, what in our game  would be "the center of the universe".
So we can think of a model of a toy-universe  using a set of initial conditions and simple set of rules that ends up describing a set of orbi-curves able to describe some fundamental geometric shapes flexible enough to create everything else, all monads information being  governed by local phenomena and the timing and syncing governed by a binary clock at the center of the universe.
¿How does a mathematician think about designing/describing ad-hoc bridges between binary counting, geometric shapes, monads, vectors using complex numbers?
I know many of the relations described here are well known, and that periodicity has enhanced meanings in different contexts, but I'd love some one to point me to some reading discussing these kind of constructions.
About why choosing the word Monad for the toy-universe game
We can think of a monad as a virtual particle, that is able to "reflect" or "refract" some information with it's own essential bias, a feature that can be seen as a color or an associated symbol  .
Another way we can imagine a monad for our experiment is as a musical note able to create in connection with others a geometry that is predictable by our brains, making it more enjoyable.
When I think of  monads I think about an "a-priori-random"  set of events that leave as a trace of their occurrence a set of "a-priori-indivisible" entities that have some information associated to them, and this information can be thought as a biased-reflection of their immediate context and the whole system state, but at the same time these entities have their own essence given  by the "universe-architect" at the "beginning", being able to position the monad in context with others, in a specific spatial and temporal coordinate, working as some kind of universe-building-celular-automata governed by the simplest central rules (Central binary clock or "Drum").
But using Wikipedia we see some of the real meanings of the word:

In philosophy: An ultimate atom, or simple, unextended point; something ultimate and indivisible.

In functional programming: A data type which represents a specific form of computation, along with the operations "return" and "bind".

In category theory: A monoid object in the category of endo-functors of a fixed category. ¿¿¿What???

Co-monad as  a monad of the opposite category. This makes me think for example "monads" 1 with -1 as the main items in the category positive and negative integers, but also as a sense of direction in space like spin.

For context we should mention Leibniz's "La Monadologie"

Leibniz surmised that there are indefinitely many substances individually 'programmed' to act in a predetermined way, each substance being coordinated with all the others.

This is the pre-established harmony which solved the mind-body problem, but at the cost of declaring any interaction between substances a mere appearance.


The clock at the center of the universe
We can imagine a tick of a clock in the center of the toy-universe, that is there from the beginning. Each tick is transmitted to the whole universe through
a  time-wave that travels "instantaneously" everywhere bringing motion to everything that is being built since the "Big Drum Celular Automata Process" started.
Why binary counting
We can imagine each monad in the system as being created and transformed by every tick of the clock. This can be thought as some kind of universal digital circuit, where a main clock syncs everything with everything else. In this toy-universe-game the idea is to allow this central clock to provide a geometry where "reality" is displayed.
Binary counting and coordinate shifting of a curve in space
Given N "monads" describing  a curve in space $\vec{\mathbf{X_n}}$ , created by a single array of complex numbers $Z_n$
$$\vec{\mathbf{X_n}}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
Considering:
$$n  \in \space \mathbb{N}_0$$
$$T_o  \in \space \mathbb{R}$$
We have
$$\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T_o}}$$
And
$$Z_n=r_n\omega^n$$
$$\overline{Z_n}=r_n\omega^{-n}$$
The modulus of $Z_n$ can have many growth rules, for the initial set of examples we will use the following recursive rules to keep things simple:
$$|Z_n|=r_n$$
Coloring
The color $C_n$ in these examples is based on  "hsv" or "coolwarm" colormaps with $M_c$ colors:
$$C_n \equiv n \pmod{M_{c}}$$
Designing the modulus of $Z_n$ recursively
For a given positive integer $M$, as the maximum amount of monads allowed per same-radius-circumference, and a real number $\Delta r_o$ defining in this case the discrete growth of r_n every time $n \equiv 0 \pmod{M}$.
$$
r_k=
\begin{cases}
0 &  k  < 0 \\
r_{k-1}+\Delta r_o & \space k \geq 0 \text{ and } k \equiv 0 \pmod{M} \\
r_{k-1} & \space   k \geq 0 \text{ and } k \not\equiv 0 \pmod{M}
\end{cases}
$$
Considering:
$$  k  \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$ \Delta r_o \in \mathbb{R}$$
So we can imagine a "discrete-time" main index for the model of creation process in the proposed toy-universe:
$$n=[0,1,2,3,4,...,N-1]$$
We define the main set of arrays describing a curve in space
$$\vec{\mathbf{X_n}}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
$$\Omega_o=\frac{2\pi }{T_o}$$
And the spatial coordinates arrays for index $n$
$$u_n=\frac{1}{2}(Z_n+\overline{Z_n})=r_n cos[\Omega_o n]$$
$$v_n=\frac{1}{2i}(Z_n-\overline{Z_n})=r_n sin[\Omega_o n]$$
$$w_n=\frac{log(|Z_n|)}{log(2)}$$
So we have an analogous way to see that:
$$Z_n=u_n+iv_n$$
$$\overline{Z_n}=u_n-iv_n$$
So from a simple 2D numbers array $Z_n$, we can construct  8 curves in space , given by the $2^{3}$ symmetries in the positive $w$ direction
Consider:
$$R_n=\frac{v_n}{u_n}$$
$$\vec{\mathbf{V_n}}=(k_u u_n,k_v v_n,k_w w_n)$$

xyz x4 - Four basic symmetries for a complex number




Binary
Decimal
Curve
LSb Symmetry
$k_u$
$k_v$
$k_w$




000
0
A
$u_n+ iv_n$
1
1
1


001
1
B
$u_n- iv_n$
1
-1
1


010
2
C
$-u_n+ iv_n$
-1
1
1


011
3
D
$-u_n- iv_n$
-1
- 1
1




yxz x4 - Four basic symmetries for a coordinate shift on a complex number




Binary
Decimal
Curve
LSb Symmetry
$k_u$
$k_v$
$k_w$




100
4
E
$v_n +iu_n$
$R_n$
$\frac{1}{R_n}$
1


101
5
F
$v_n -iu_n$
$R_n$
$-\frac{1}{R_n}$
1


110
6
G
$-v_n +iu_n$
$-R_n$
$\frac{1}{R_n}$
1


111
7
H
$-v_n -iu_n$
$-R_n$
$-\frac{1}{R_n}$
1



We could continue this table for $k_w=-1$, with the mirrored curves totaling  $2^4$ mirrored curves
This change is iust to indicate more clearly that up to 48 curves can be created mirroring the same $\vec{X}$, being the first 8 paths:
$$\vec{X_n}=(k_u u_n,k_v v_n,k_w w_n)$$
For example an array describing a set of curves we will call "Flower" uses 8 mirrored arrays :

xyz x4

$$\vec{A_n}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{B_n}=(u_n,-v_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{C_n}=(-u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{D_n}=(-u_n,-v_n,w_n)$$

yxz x4

$$\vec{E_n}=(v_n,u_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{F_n}=(v_n,-u_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{G_n}=(-v_n,u_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{H_n}=(-v_n,-u_n,w_n)$$
Other alphabets describing  mirrored set of curves
Following the previous logic, we can imagine:
"Wormhole" structure created by counting
"Wormhole" using 16 Mirrored curves :

xyz x4

$$\vec{A_n}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{B_n}=(u_n,-v_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{C_n}=(-u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{D_n}=(-u_n,-v_n,w_n)$$

yxz x4

$$\vec{E_n}=(v_n,u_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{F_n}=(v_n,-u_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{G_n}=(-v_n,u_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{H_n}=(-v_n,-u_n,w_n)$$

xy(-z) x4
$$\vec{I_n}=(u_n,v_n,-w_n)$$

$$\vec{J_n}=(u_n,-v_n,-w_n)$$
$$\vec{K_n}=(-u_n,v_n,-w_n)$$
$$\vec{L_n}=(-u_n,-v_n,-w_n)$$

yx(-z) x4
$$\vec{M_n}=(v_n,u_n,-w_n)$$

$$\vec{N_n}=(v_n,-u_n,-w_n)$$
$$\vec{O_n}=(-v_n,u_n,-w_n)$$
$$\vec{P_n}=(-v_n,-u_n,-w_n)$$
"Atomic" structure created by counting
"Atom" structure uses 6*8=48 curves using all possible basic-combinations of shifted coordinates :
$F_0$

xyz x4

$$\vec{A_n}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{B_n}=(u_n,-v_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{C_n}=(-u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{D_n}=(-u_n,-v_n,w_n)$$

yxz x4

$$\vec{E_n}=(v_n,u_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{F_n}=(v_n,-u_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{G_n}=(-v_n,u_n,w_n)$$
$$\vec{H_n}=(-v_n,-u_n,w_n)$$
$F_1$

xy(-z) x4
$$\vec{I_n}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)$$

$$\vec{i_n}=(u_n,-v_n,-w_n)$$
$$\vec{K_n}=(-u_n,v_n,-w_n)$$
$$\vec{L_n}=(-u_n,-v_n,-w_n)$$

yx(-z) x4
$$\vec{M_n}=(v_n,u_n,-w_n)$$

$$\vec{N_n}=(v_n,-u_n,-w_n)$$
$$\vec{O_n}=(-v_n,u_n,-w_n)$$
$$\vec{P_n}=(-v_n,-u_n,-w_n)$$
$F_2$

zxy x4

$$\vec{Q_n}=(w_n,u_n,v_n)$$
$$\vec{R_n}=(w_n,u_n,-v_n)$$
$$\vec{S_n}=(w_n,-u_n,v_n)$$
$$\vec{T_n}=(w_n,-u_n,-v_n)$$

zyx x4

$$\vec{U_n}=(w_n,v_n,u_n)$$
$$\vec{V_n}=(w_n,v_n,-u_n)$$
$$\vec{W_n}=(w_n,-v_n,u_n)$$
$$\vec{X_n}=(w_n,-v_n,-u_n)$$
$F_3$

(-z)xy x4

$$\vec{\alpha_n}=(-w_n,u_n,v_n)$$
$$\vec{\beta_n}=(-w_n,u_n,-v_n)$$
$$\vec{\gamma_n}=(-w_n,-u_n,v_n)$$
$$\vec{\delta_n}=(-w_n,-u_n,-v_n)$$

(-z)yx x4

$$\vec{\epsilon_n}=(-w_n,v_n,u_n)$$
$$\vec{\zeta_n}=(-w_n,v_n,-u_n)$$
$$\vec{\eta_n}=(-w_n,-v_n,u_n)$$
$$\vec{\theta_n}=(-w_n,-v_n,-u_n)$$
$F_4$

xzy x4

$$\vec{\iota_n}=(u_n,w_n,v_n)$$
$$\vec{\kappa_n}=(u_n,w_n,-v_n)$$
$$\vec{\lambda_n}=(-u_n,w_n,v_n)$$
$$\vec{\mu_n}=(-u_n,w_n,-v_n)$$

yzx x4

$$\vec{\nu_n}=(v_n,w_n,u_n)$$
$$\vec{\xi_n}=(v_n,w_n,-u_n)$$
$$\vec{O_n}=(-v_n,w_n,u_n)$$
$$\vec{\pi_n}=(-v_n,w_n,-u_n)$$
$F_5$

x(-z)y x4

$$\vec{\rho_n}=(u_n,-w_n,v_n)$$
$$\vec{\sigma_n}=(u_n,-w_n,-v_n)$$
$$\vec{\tau_n}=(-u_n,-w_n,v_n)$$
$$\vec{\upsilon_n}=(-u_n,-w_n,-v_n)$$

y(-z)x x4

$$\vec{\phi_n}=(v_n,-w_n,u_n)$$
$$\vec{\chi_n}=(v_n,-w_n,-u_n)$$
$$\vec{\psi_n}=(-v_n,-w_n,u_n)$$
$$\vec{\omega_n}=(-v_n,-w_n,-u_n)$$

Maybe you'd be interested in "almost periodic functions", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function – the topic has also come up here, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430676/almost-periodic-function and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659699/an-example-of-almost-periodic-function and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728480/almost-periodic-function-vs-quasi-periodic-function

Thank you so much! I added at the end of my attempt of an answer reference to the context you pointed out of almost periodic functions and $n^{-s}$

Gerry, The system offers me to start a bounty,but I'm not sure. What should I do before doing that? Make the question much better before? Improve my own attempt of an answer? Divide the question into shorter new questions? Thanks

@GerryMyerson there are comments for you for which you might not have received a notification.

@p from FAQ see How do comment @replies work? I saw your comment because I'm specifically following the question, but to ensure a user gets a notification that you've responded, don't forget to use the @ feature and the autocomplete. As for your comment - are you sure the question is currently clear enough and can be answered directly, rather than just a "here's what I'm thinking about" announcement?

@uhoh thanks! I'm not sure what to do. I was reading about when to make a bounty, but not sure how easy to understand or how long is too long for a question answer(I saw a post in meta about this)

In order for someone to respond with an answer post, they'll want to know the actual question being asked to which an answer is possible. You might consider posting a new, short, clear, concise question post, and linking back here for background. For example, this is an actual question: "¿How does a mathematician think about designing/describing ad-hoc bridges between binary counting, geometric shapes, monads, vectors using complex numbers?" If it's what you'd like to ask, make it the title of a new post, explain briefly in the body, and add a link back here for background.

@phionez give potential answer authors confidence that they really know the question to which you want an answer, so they know that there's a chance their answer post will do the job.

@uhoh maybe you can help me. If I'm using complex sequences the sampling theorem get's modified because I have the impression that would be really easy to prove that to avoid aliasing in this extended sense you need $f_s\geq\varphi f $ . But I think I remember reading that being the sequences 2D, being the $f_s > f$ it's enough because we have really 2 correlated samples per sampling period $T_s$. The question is to know if in this context, I should correct the $f_s \geq 2 f$ statement

@phionez then post exactly that as a new, short, concise question post! The page here is so incredibly long that most will just avoid it and move on. You've done a great job of articulating an actual question in your comment, but potential answer authors won't see it until you post it as a new question. Go for it!

@uho, thanks, and thanks for carrying the ball here. As it happens, I did see the first comment, because I checked back to see whether there was any reply to my comment, but I hadn't seen the second one yet.

About the $f_s$ question the first impression is that the construction is just making some kind of XPSK modulation of the $r_k$ , so here we need to consider baud rate, not just $f_s$ if we are going to talk about aliasing of symbols

@uho I made the previous search before making a question about the $f_s$ and it might be something there to explore. Is as in the constructions with almost periodic functions, just describe the context where you define periodicity and construct the auxiliary machinery to  justify it. But there are many questions here about extended shannon i.e: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362514/nyquist-shannon-theorems-for-different-sampling-models
So I'm thinking on how to title it so it's not redundant

@uhoh : I started this question and I'm cleaning it up. Looking forward to your comments https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4931222/4d-varphi-gons-how-do-i-precisely-define-extend-a-context-where-f-s-varp

Great - the title is a clear, concise question! I'll follow it to see how things go.

About the question
I'm sorry, I think the question was vague, because I really wanted to make a wider question but while writing it I focused on the part about periodicity with some big omissions.
I fix that now, and I think this answers the title of my question.Maybe someone can add a better answer after this.
The idea in the question about using mirrored curves is related to an idea of other way of watching correlation or  periodicity using the superposed orbits for that. But maybe that requires a new question.
Rationality and Periodicity
$$\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T_o}}$$
$$n \in \mathbb{N}_0$$
Let's analyze periodicity of $\omega^n$ with these restrictions being $p_o$ and $q_o$ integers:
$$T_o=\frac{p_o}{q_o}$$
$$T_o \in \mathbb{Q}$$
For a chosen $p_o$ and $q_o$ we want to find values of P such as
$$\omega^{n+P}=\omega^{n}$$
$$\omega^{n}\omega^{P}=\omega^{n}$$
As we are going to choose $p_o$ and $q_o$ as integers that  provide a rational number as close as possible to an irrational.So we have to add an extra restriction :
$$ p_o \not\equiv 0 \pmod{q_o}$$
For
$$k,k_o \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$\omega^{P}=e^{2\pi i k}=\omega^{kT_o}$$
Meaning:
$$P=kT_o=k\frac{p_o}{q_o}$$
it's valid only for restricted $k$
$$ k \equiv 0 \pmod{q_o}$$
For $k=k_oq_o$ we have
$$P=k_o q_o\frac{p_o}{q_o}=k_op_o$$
So the periods can be multiples of $p_o$
In the example of  $T_o=\varphi$ and the $M_c=13$ in the coloring being in the Fibonacci sequence, it made a nice plot but  not periodic in the sense I was looking for, but it made me lose myself into the spirals instead of properly thinking that for example taking a worse approximation of $\varphi$ using:
$$T_o=\frac{F_N}{F_{N-1 }}$$
$F_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number
For big values of $N$ we get better and better approximations
$M=1$ $M_c=13$ and $T_o=\frac{2584}{1597}$
This shows how good the approximation of the irrational is, as you get a similar plot as in the question.

$M=1$ $M_c=p_o=2584$ and $T_o=\frac{2584}{1597}$
So If the analysis I made before works, I should see the colors growing along the string, not in other spirals as it was in using the wrong $M_c$ for the purpose.
The resulting image should look like the examples given in the question where $T_o$ was a big integer.

The rational approximation of the value of $\varphi$ in the question
In the question plots the approximation is :
$$T_o=\frac{1618033988749895}{ 10^{15}}$$
But using that same $T_o$ but considering $M_c=2548$ you still get a similar ordering of the colors:
$M=1$ $M_c=2584$ $T_o=\frac{1618033988749895}{10^{15}}$

It looks like it works. Looking closely we see :

Here  $M=1$ $M_c=p_o=2584$ and $T_o=\frac{2584}{1597}$  in hsv from the beginning

Rationality of continuous time frequency
We can imagine a continuous-time function as a 2D number like:
$$\theta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T}}$$
For simplicity, the   continuous-time can be considered as $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and let's add some more restrictions
$$T \in \mathbb{Q}$$
$$f \in \mathbb{Q}$$
$$n \in \mathbb{N}_0$$
$$ q,p \space \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$T=1/f$$
$$f=q/p$$
$$\theta^t=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T}t}$$
We will consider cases where $q/p$ is integer,rational and make it also a rational approximation of an irrational number.
To get a valid discrete-time sequence representing this continuous time function we need to choose a sampling frequency:
$$f_s=\frac{1}{T_s}$$
$$\theta^{nT_s}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T}nT_s}$$
$$\theta^{nT_s}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{\frac{T}{T_s}}n}$$
So by Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem we know that to avoid aliasing we need :
$$f_s \geq 2f$$
We want $f_s$ to be positive integer, allowing us to find an integer period  $P$ for our discrete-time signal.
Discrete-time function  as a 2D number $\omega$
$$\omega^n$$
$$T_o \in \mathbb{Q}$$
$$ P,k_o,k \space \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$T_o \geq 2$$
$$T_o=\frac{f_s}{f}=\frac{T}{T_s}$$
$$\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T_o}}$$
$$\theta^{nT_s}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T_o}n}=\omega^{n}$$
$$\omega^{n+P}=\omega^{n}$$
$$\omega^{n}\omega^{P}=\omega^{n}$$
$$\omega^{P}=e^{2k\pi i}=\omega^{kT_o}$$
$$P=kT_o$$
$$P=k \frac{f_s}{f}$$
$$P=k \frac{f_s}{\frac{q}{p}}$$
$$P=k \frac{p}{q}f_s$$
This is valid por restricted k
$$k=k_oq$$
$$P=k_o p f_s$$
So the periods are going to be affected by the combination of $k_o,q,p$ and the selected $f_s$
Not all irrationals are created equal and Why are Most Polygons Impossible to Construct?:
I think a similar approach can be used for $T_o=\sqrt{2}$ using a good approximation . Im sure I'm missing something in this explanation, but it's a good start.
Another Roof channel made a video that is a gem about the formal foundations of all this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gdy1u4lsjDw
Almost Periodic Functions
The comment from Gerry has really interesting reads on for example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function
This led me to make a similar construction using:
$$ s  \in \mathbb{C}$$
$$ n  \in \mathbb{N}$$
In this case we have to remove 0 from the natural numbers:
$$n \geq 1$$
$$ s=\sigma+i \omega t$$
$$\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$$
$$\zeta_{n}(\sigma,\omega,t)= n^{-s}=e^{-\sigma log(n)}e^{-ilog(n) \frac{2\pi}{T}t} $$
For a "carefully selected" $T_o=\frac{T}{T_s}$ and $\sigma$ we could write:
$$ n^{-s} \approx Z_n=e^{-\sigma log(n)}e^{-i (log(n) \frac{2\pi}{T}T_s) n} $$
$$\omega_n= -log(n) \frac{2\pi}{T_o}$$
$$ n^{-s} \approx e^{-\sigma log(n)}e^{i \omega_n n} $$
Or instead of using a fixed $T_o$ and $\sigma$ we make them sequences as well as carefully curated  "modular" functions  $f$ and $g$
$$T_n=f[n]$$
and
$$\sigma_n=g[n]$$
Backward differences sequences -  Newton discrete calculus & meaning of the discrete-j*rk
I imagine this is somehow related to this fact you easily realize while doing the higher order backward differences on any sequence and see the pascal triangle pattern emerge:
$$\Delta^N Z_n = \sum_{k=0}^{N} (-1)^k \binom{N}{k} Z_{n-k}$$
Note that this is closely related to :
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{N}{N \choose k}\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{N}\right) = \Im\sum_{k = 0}^{N}{N \choose k}\left(\exp\left(\frac{i \pi}{N}\right)\right)^{k} =
\Im\left(1 + \exp\left(\frac{i \pi}{N}\right)\right)^{N}
$$
So
$$
2^{N}\left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2N}\right)\right|^{N}
$$
The natural numbers represented as colors $C_n$  are cyclic and produce an interesting set of loop sequences for the initial example with initial conditions $T_o=\varphi$ and $M_c=13$
$$C_n \equiv n \pmod{M_{c}}$$
If we call the first difference speed, the second acceleration the third  receives an unfortunate name we all try to avoid being or being around.
0,8,3,11,6,1,9,4,12,7,2,10,5 being in A257961 and A025636 should explain how n mod 13 worked as a combination machine , being 13 the constant value of  the first backward difference of enough order   to provide a constant integer sequence?
For loop 0,8,3,11,6,1,9,4,12,7,2,10,5 if I remember correctly it's the 3'd order difference that  is constant 13. Being as well the result of adding of the (0+1)th and (13-1)th elements.

The same happens for the $(0+k)$th and the $(M_c-k)$th elements added are also $M_c$

OEIS - Cellular automata sequences and binary counting
I started reading about Cantor's dust, and ended up here:
https://oeis.org/wiki/Index_to_OEIS:_Section_Ce#cell
Specially About the pascal triangle pattern emerging:  A047999 and A102037 showing how it can be implemented with logic gates see this by Wolfram:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiSieve.html
"Gardner (1977) and independently Watkins (Conway and Guy 1996, Krížek et al. 2001) noticed that the number of sides for constructible polygons with odd Numbers of sides are given by the first 32 rows of the Sierpiński sieve interpreted as binary numbers, giving 1, 3, 5, 15, 17, 51, 85, 255, ... (OEIS A004729, Conway and Guy 1996, p. 140). In other words, every row is a product of distinct Fermat primes, with terms given by binary counting.
"
Circle of fifths  creating Sierpiński triangle shape algorithm by counting:
Saw this initially here:
https://youtube.com/shorts/A7xMJ639gAw?si=vr9JzHWUt7zdFeHt

Draw the circle of fifths as an HSV colored wheel with M=12 slots using M colors and add M labels for the notes. radius=1
['A','D','G','C','F','Bb','Eb','Ab','Db','Gb','B','E'] is mapped to an index

$$k=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]$$
The position in the complex plane for the circle of fifths and its 12 notes is given by
$$S_k=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{M}k}$$

Randomly choose a point inside a unitary circle - Express it as a complex number
$$Z_o=r_o e^{\phi_o}$$
There are many ways to select a random point inside a unitary circle,we try selecting a radius and and an angle, as if we where doing it with a compass.
$$r_{min}<r_o<r_{max}$$
and
$$-\pi<\phi_o<\pi$$
With a resolution $M_c$ points per interval

Randomly choose between this three notes $(A_b,E,C) or (7,11,3) $ note in the circle of fifths
and express it as a complex number $Z_{note}=S_k$ using the mapping given by the index
$$S_k=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{M}k}$$
always expressing the notes in this order:
['A','D','G','C','F','Bb','Eb','Ab','Db','Gb','B','E']
$$0<k<M-1$$
$$k=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]$$

A_b is k=7

E is k=11

C is k=3



Draw a line between $Z_o$ and $Z_{note}$

Find the mid point between $Z_o$ and $Z_{note}$ and call it $Z_{\frac{1}{2}}$

Set $Z_o=Z_{\frac{1}{2}}$ and repeat $N_{iter}$ times from step 2 using this new value of $Z_o$ in step 3




Computational Complexity and irrational numbers
Here in MS I found this interesting context :
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307157
"
There are only a countable number of Turing Machines, thus a countable number of algorithms for computing irrational numbers. But there are an uncountable number of irrational numbers. So we cannot compute them all.
"
How to create ellipses and square orbits. From introducing the most basic epicycles to the Gibbs phenomenon
What would have happened if Ptolemy met Fourier and Lissajous ?
Epicycles and the heat equation would have met as well(or any other feature we can model as a color in the proposed model).
Maybe they ended up trying to add more and more epicycles to end up describing a square orbit just for the pleasure of it.
Using $Z_t$ as a short way to write some $z(t)$ we can imagine they wrote something like this after a long night:
$$ R_{p} , R_{q} \in \mathbb{C}$$
$$Z_t=R_{p} e^{i\omega t} +R_{q} e^{-i\omega t}$$
$$Z_t=R_{p} e^{i\omega t} +R_{q} e^{-i\omega t}$$
$$|R_p|>|R_q|$$
$$F_{pq}=\pm 2\sqrt{R_p R_q}$$


https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307157

About the pascal triangle pattern add reference to A047999 and A102037 showing how it can be implemented with logic gates see this  by Wolfram https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiSieve.html

0,8,3,11,6,1,9,4,12,7,2,10,5 being in A257961 and A025636 to explain why mod 13 worked as a combination machine , being 13 the first backward difference of enough order to provide a constant sequence?

Added for context on the backward differences and reconstruction signals as in this ms question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2371853

Se how "complex-golden-ratios" $\varphi_i^n=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{6}n}$ is a 6-gon generator and $\varphi_j^n=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}n}$ is a 3-gon generator.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856811/is-the-imaginary-golden-ratio-unique

As all n-gons can be thought as a composition of triangles I feel that $\varphi_j$ is the coolest one, because by shifting and scaling can generate all the others.
Note 0,8,3,11,6,1,9,4,12,7,2,10,5  in A257961 and how this one emerges when labeling the vertex of growing-radius  and periodically shifted 13-gons ($\varphi$-gons) when using as large N as necessary  in $\varphi =F_N/F_{N-1}=f_s/f=T/T_s$ in   $$r_{n} e^{\frac{2\pi i}{\varphi}n}$$

Leibniz about time : "For my part, I have said several times that I hold space to be something merely relative, as time is, taking space to be an order of coexistences, as time is an order of successions. For space indicates... an order of things existing at the same time, considered just as existing together, without bringing in any details about what they are like. When we see a number of things together, one becomes aware of this order among them."
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/is-spacetime-a-compound-substance-in-liebnizs-monadology?rq=1

"We may regard the present state of the universe as the effect of its past and the cause of its future. An intellect which at a certain moment would knowallforcesthatsetnatureinmotion, and all positions of all items of which nature is composed, if this intellect were also vast enough to submit these data to analysis, it would embrace in a single formula the movements of the greatest bodies of the universe and those of the tiniest atom; for such an intellect nothing would be uncertain and the future just like the past would be present before its eyes. " https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2401259

Reference the 24-cell , specially it's orthogonal projection $F_4$ Witth dihedral symmetry 12 . And the 48 root vectors of the $F_4$ group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell#/media/File:F4_roots_by_24-cell_duals.svg

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4946966/introduction-to-the-binary-tetrahedral-group-and-the-24-cell

https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jgth-2021-0131/html
