Introduction to the Binary Tetrahedral group and the 24-cell
Context and introduction
I was playing with complex number sequences $Z_n=r_n\omega^n=u_n+iv_n$ represented in space and realized that it's always possible to associate up to 48 naturally symmetric curves associated to the initial curve by doing binary manipulations and shifts on the coordinates.
$$\vec{X}_n=u_n\hat{i}+v_n\hat{j}+f(|Z_n|)\hat{k}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)$$
The reason why I mention the number 48 here in the introduction will be more clear in this text later.
Now because of doing research to find references where binary counting is present in the emergence of symmetries of geometric figures in space, I was introduced to the idea of the 24-cell, and the geometry related to it. I feel I have the motivation to finally understand quaternions by playing with this object. So I started doing some experiments  starting with one of the basic projections of the 24-cell by doing this basic construction where these questions arise:
My attempt to find the logic in the Binary tetrahedral group
Q1: I can't understand  why the elements of the group are "order 6" for $s$ and $t$ and "order 3" or "order 4" for the other binary combinations. I understand it refers to the order of the elements, as in the least number of times an action must be applied to the element to get the identity element, but can't understand how is done here. (see edit at the end on this question)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tetrahedral_group#/media/File:Binary_tetrahedral_group_elements.png
Q2:
In this construction, we will find that
$$r^2=s^3=t^3=-1$$
Why is this  important in projections, I imagine is some normalization but can't find it's motivation as a general idea.
(edit)
Reading the answer from R.J I realize where my confusion might be. In the graph from Wikipedia says $r=k$ , and I ended up mixing the projection data with the quaternions.
$$r^2=(-1)=e^{\pi i}$$
So $r$ is an order 4 generator? It's a 4-gon generator in it's projection and generates the axis of the projection by:
$$r=e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{4}}=i$$
But they are not simple complex numbers, they are quaternions, so $i$ here cant be just a complex number.
$$s=\frac{1}{2}(1+i+j+k)$$
$$t=\frac{1}{2}(1+i+j-k)$$
So both are order 6 generators because $s^6=t^6=1$
And I  solved for $j$ and $k$ fixing $r=i$ and considering $r^2=s^3=t^3=-1$ to see the shape of the projection :
$$r=i$$
$$s=e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$t=e^{\frac{-\pi i}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Note we get the imaginary golden ratio  Imaginary Golden Ratio

Solving for $j$ and $k$ we get:
$$k=s-t=i\sqrt{3}$$
$$s+t=1+i+j$$
$$j=s+t-1-i=1+i\sqrt{3}-1-i=i(\sqrt{3}-1)$$
$$(i,j,k)=(i,\sqrt{3}i,(\sqrt{3}-1)i)$$

Trying to check if this manipulations arrive to something useful I realize that these expressions have Hurwitz expansion as a continued fraction:

$$\hat{s}=\frac{1}{2}(1+i+\sqrt{3}i+\sqrt{3}i-i)=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{3}i= \frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}e^{i tan^{-1}(2 \sqrt{3})}$$
$$\hat{t}=\frac{1}{2}(1+i+\sqrt{3}i-\sqrt{3}i+i)=\frac{1}{2}+i=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}e^{i tan^{-1}(2)}$$

Are $\hat{s}$ and $\hat{t}$ used in some projection?

Q3: Considering this why, are $r,s,t$ special ?
Initial attempt to understand the projection in the complex plane
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tetrahedral_group#/media/File:Binary_tetrahedral_group_elements.png
$$n \geq 0 \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T_o}}$$
(+1)- Order 1

(+1)  (Magenta Axis)
$$1=\omega^0=\omega^{T_o n}=e^{2\pi i n}$$

(-1)- Order 2

(-1) - Label (2) - (Magenta Axis)

$$-1=\omega^{\frac{T_o}{2}(2n+1)}=e^{i \pi (2n+1)}$$
6 - Order 4 - These are the 6 faces of a cube
Cartesian coordinates - orthogonal axis
$$(u_n,v_n,w_n)=u_n\hat i+v_n\hat j+w_n\hat k$$



Binary
Expression
Order
Axis




000
$\hat i = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{8}} = e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}} = \omega^{\frac{T_o}{8}}$
4
Red Axis


001
$-\hat i = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{8} + i\pi} = e^{\frac{\pi i}{4} + i\pi} = \omega^{\frac{T_o}{8}}\omega^{\frac{T_o}{2}(2n+1)}$
4
Red Axis


010
$\hat j = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{4}} = e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}} = \omega^{\frac{T_o}{4}}$
4
Green Axis


011
$-\hat j = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{4} + i\pi} = e^{\frac{\pi i}{2} + i\pi} = \omega^{\frac{T_o}{4}}\omega^{\frac{T_o}{2}(2n+1)}$
4
Green Axis


100
$r=\hat k = e^{3\frac{2\pi i}{8}} = e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}} = \omega^{\frac{3T_o}{8}}$
4
Blue Axis


101
$-\hat k = e^{3\frac{2\pi i}{8} + i\pi} = e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4} + i\pi} = \omega^{\frac{3T_o}{8}}\omega^{\frac{T_o}{2}(2n+1)}$
4
Blue Axis



8 Order 6 -> $+ 1 \pm  a \hat i \pm b \hat j \pm c \hat k$ - Green



Binary
Expression
Order




0000
$s=(1 +  \hat i + \hat j + \hat k)/2 $
6


0001
$t=(1 +  \hat i + \hat j  -\hat k)/2 $
6


0010
$(1 +  \hat i - \hat j + \hat k)/2 $
6


0011
$(1 +  \hat i - \hat j  - \hat k)/2 $
6


0100
$(1   -\hat i + \hat j +  \hat k)/2 $
6


0101
$(1   -\hat i + \hat j   -\hat k)/2 $
6


0110
$(1   -\hat i  -\hat j +  \hat k)/2 $
6


0111
$(1   -\hat i  -\hat j   -\hat k)/2 $
6



8 Order 3 -> $- 1 \pm  a \hat i \pm b \hat j \pm c \hat k$ - Blue



Binary
Expression
Order




1000
$(-1 +  \hat i + \hat j + \hat k)/2 $
3


1001
$(-1 +  \hat i + \hat j  -\hat k)/2 $
3


1010
$(-1 +  \hat i - \hat j + \hat k)/2 $
3


1011
$(-1 +  \hat i - \hat j  - \hat k)/2 $
3


1100
$(-1   -\hat i + \hat j +  \hat k)/2 $
3


1101
$(-1   -\hat i + \hat j   -\hat k)/2 $
3


1110
$(-1   -\hat i  -\hat j +  \hat k)/2 $
3


1111
$(-1   -\hat i  -\hat j   -\hat k)/2 $
3



So I made some code to test if I was correctly decoding the projection and made some plots with it in 2D.

Q4: I made this plot using a $T_o=48$ because it looked like a sufficient enough resolution  to encode the 24 elements in the projection into the unit circle as 16 unique angles using an expression of the form $r_n e^{\frac{2\pi i}{48}k}$ for $k=3n$ , being $r_n$ the appropriate modulus for the correspondent element  of the projection. I was trying to construct this but realized that might be already done and have a common expression for $r_n \in \mathbb{C} $ that produces a phase shift along with the radius. Maybe this a way to get the Cayley Graph? Is 48 special in this context?

About Q1 (edit)
I understand what the order of a group is (The number of elements in the group) , and how is different to the order of an element (as the least number of times that an action must be applied to go to the identity element) . But in this group I can't see how is being done, and why are those the order of the elements on the cases of order 6, 3 and 4.
To help potential answers to the question to know the  starting level I add context some basic context and definitions.
Definition of a group
Definition:
•A group is a non-empty set $G$ together with a rule that assigns to
each pair g, h of elements of $G$ an element $g ∗ h$  that satisfies certain conditions:
•(closed) $g ∗ h \in G$. We say that $G$ is closed under $∗$
•(associative) $g ∗ (h ∗ k) = (g ∗ h) ∗ k$ for all $g, h, k \in G$. We say that $∗$ is associative.
•(identity) There exists an identity element $d \in G$ such that for all $g \in G$
$$d ∗ g = g ∗ d = g$$
•(inverse) Every element $g \in G$ has an inverse $g^{-1}$
such that:
$$g * g^{-1}=d$$
Terminology
I understand this as the most abstract way to study  symmetry. For example thinking on the different ways a square can be rotated with different actions, and recognizing how some combination of actions are equivalent to other simple actions.
"Roughly speaking, a symmetry of an object is a bijection (i.e. one-to-one correspondence) from the object to itself that preserves its structure."
https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~mwemyss/teaching/3alg1-7.pdf
For example thinking about what are all the "actions" we can take on a square that leave it in an indistinguishable state from the state you started allows you to understand the 8 symmetries in the "Dihedral Group of order 8"
Each action is called a symmetry of the square (in this case we have eight):



binary
Decimal
Action
Expression




000
0
Doing nothing
$z \mapsto z e^{2\pi i}=1z$


001
1
Rotation Counterclockwise 90º
$z \mapsto z e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}=iz$


010
2
180º rotation (can be done clockwise or anticlockwise)
$z \mapsto z e^{i\pi}=-z$


011
3
Clockwise 90º rotation
$z \mapsto z e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}}=-iz$


100
4
Flipping along horizontal $y=0$ axis
$z \mapsto \overline{z}$


101
5
Flipping along diagonal $y=x$ axis
$z \mapsto \overline{z}e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}} $


110
6
Flipping along vertical $x=0$ axis
$z \mapsto -\overline{z}$


111
7
Flipping along diagonal $y=-x$ axis
$z \mapsto -\overline{z}e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}} $



In these expressions, $z$ is a complex number and $\overline{z}$ represents its complex conjugate. This is a way to express these actions with an operation with complex numbers.


As I understood your text, if $r^2=(-1)=e^{\pi i}$ then it is possible that $r=k$ and so the conclusion
$r=e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}=i$ can be wrong. There are many square roots of $-1$ among the quaternions, not only $i$, but also $-i$, and $\pm j$ and $\pm k$ too.

The main confusion is indeed that the text above uses complex numbers notations where the group elements are 24 special quaternions. Group multiplication is multiplication of quaternions, not multiplication of numbers in the complex plane. I think that is very explicit in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tetrahedral_group and in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion .

Thank you very much. Now I understand I was mixing the projection data with the quaternions. I will use that Caley table you shared to try and plot it following that convention.

About Q2 and in general to understand quaternions I think it's amazing to read this letter from Hamilton to Graves on October 17, 1843: https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/QLetter/QLetter.pdf

Q1: The fact that the generators squared or cubed give -1 (which has order 2) means that their order must be twice these, 4 or 6, to get +1, the unit element.
Q2: The general concept in group theory is to find a minimum set of relations between the group elements that uniquely defines the abstract group. Here we have 3 equations which appear to be a nice/convenient number using 3 generators to let 2T be different (non-isomorphic) to other (the 2 other finite) groups of order 24.
Q3: $r$, $s$ and $t$ are special because they are a set of generators of the group. k is not involved because apparently it is not having any relationship with the group.
Q4: 24 is the order of the group. So obviously any Cayley graph has 24 vertices. (The graph that is shown does not have a vertex in the center of the graph.) The Cayley graph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tetrahedral_group#/media/File:Cayley_graph_of_SL(2,3).svg
is drawn with 2 generators, one of order 4 (red edges), one of order 6 (black edges).
The Caley graph has 24 vertices, each one labelled with one of the 24 elements of the group - either enumerated from 1 to 24 or by one of the 24 quaternions. The Caley graph demonstrats that one can pick 2 generators (two group elements), one of order 4 for the red edges and one of order 6 for the black edges, such that multiplication of a group element at a vertex by the generator leads along the edge to the next vertex. It may need some sort of puzzling for a coherent match; it's not obvious from the outside which of the 6 elements of order 4 and which of the 8 elements of order 6 are consistent with the rest. (Typically there are many differnt pairs of generators that would match the rules and the Caley graph).
More properties of the group are in https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group:SL(2,3)

In Q2 -1 nor k are not regarded as generators. Generally speaking, if a generator g has order o, g^o=1, then the elements represented by g^d, where d|o, have only order d. The generic fact known a priori is that all element orders are orders of the group (see textbooks about groups.)

I think I get it now, you mean that as $k^8=e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}8}=1$ is an element and being $g=e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}$ is the main  generator of order 4 . So $g^2=-1$ ,$g^3=-i$,$g^4=1$ . Now  the element denoted as r in the projection is $k=e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}$ and it's not the generator.

I added a Calely table to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tetrahedral_group#Presentation .
The convention in that case is that element 1 is the unit element, element 3 is r, element 5 is -1, element 14 is s, and element 18 is t. By doing multiplication within the table (left element the row, right element the column) one can verify that $r^2=s^3=t^3=rst
=-1$ .
It's not certain that this information will survive (there are too many wikipedians which are deletionists.)

The cycle graph is figure 43 in https://vixra.org/pdf/1406.0183v3.pdf

thank you so much. I have to decode it now. I accepted the answer today, but I thought I did that yesterday. I corrected some things in the question, let me know if its' better to clean something up
